# Hibernate 4 Annotations. Mapping two non-related Tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate-mapping

I've got two tables in MySQL that are not related with each other in any way.

Table events:

```
 id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 date VARCHAR ,
 hour VARCHAR ,
 event VARCHAR ,
```

Table thread_events:

```
 id_te INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 diode INT 
 status BOOLEAN
```

My question is: How to map these tables with annotations in one Java Class?

Comment: Mapping two unrelated tables to one Java class doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Ok so if I make two seperate classes, how can I add these to hibernate.cfg.xml? Just add another <mapping class="..." /> ?